# Codeigniter page number properly display?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I used pagination of codeigniter....but main problem is page number not displayed properly.

In controller i used following codes:

```
$count = $this->db->count_all_results('table');

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/lists/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $count;

    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment('2');
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    if($config['uri_segment']<=0) $offset = 0;
    else $offset = ($config['uri_segment'] - 1)* 2;
    $limit = 2;
    $data['infoArr'] = $this->home_model->get_all($offset, $limit);

    $this->load->view('list_info',$data);
```

In model I used following code:

```
function get_all($offset, $limit){

    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit")->result_array();
}
```

And In view i used

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

In my table 9 information is inserted...
According to the database pagination 1 2 3 4 5 should be displayed but only 1 2 3 > Last is displayed.

When i clicked on 2 only 4 number is displayed otherwise 4 and 5 number is not displayed...
What is the main problem in code....
Please help me..

Thanks in advance for all who help me..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do a

```
$config['num_links'] = 4;
```

If you want more cases to be shown. Otherwise extend the pagination library to do what you want it to do.

Comment: thank for your help but next button not working well..it works for page number 1 and 2 then for page number 3 it display page 1....

Comment: Make sure your `$config['total_rows']` is correct, and consider extending and changing pagination library if needed.

Comment: total rows is correct and number of page display is correct but next button and previous button is not working properly.....

Comment: Then the default pagination may not be what you're after. The default pagination pretty much only show functional links. Which makes `previous` to never be shown on 1st page and `next` on last page. As mentioned, consider extending pagination library.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize this index and it will work:

```
$config['num_links'] = NUM_LINKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is due to this setting :

```
$config['per_page'] = 2;
```

The above setting is for

```
var $per_page = 10; // Max number of items you want shown per page
```

Either you change to bigger number or just let it blank (default is 10)